# Can you assign a variable a JSX Element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Working in a React/Typescript project. I currently have a constants.tsx file where I'm trying to assign and export a variable that is a JSX element.

constants.tsx

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

export const someContent: ReactNode = {
content: (
<span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <sup>Duis</sup> aute irure dolor 
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
  sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
  est laborum
</span>
   ),
};
```

I'm trying to implement it into another component that's rendering the JSX.

MainComponent.tsx

```
  return (
     <div>
       {someContent}
     </div>    
  )
```

It's a rather large component so I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible. I kept it really minimized in this case.  I don't see static content worth being written out in the main component.  But it does work if I were to manually code out each text and html tag in the main component.

**The Problem:**
Starting from the span to the closing span, it doesn't recognize the variable as a JSX element.  I hovered my cursor on the span and it says "Cannot find name 'span'". Is there something I'm missing?

`constants.tsx` error:

[image]

**UPDATE**

So my constants.tsx file was constant.ts. So when I fixed the typo, it worked.

Comment: The variable being exported is not a react node, its just an object.

Comment: Can you recreate this in the typescript playground? When I tried, I got no errors: https://tsplay.dev/DWKDGw. That said, any reason to not just make this a component? You could then simply: `<SomeContent />`